# Quais as diferenças entre as versões do jQuery normal e o slim?

Tags: jquery

Na última versão do jQuery, 3.0, foi anunciado a versão *slim*. Quais as diferença desta versão *slim* para a versão jQuery 3.0 regular?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A Slim não possui:

- os módulos de AJAX, porque é comum as pessoas usarem outro mecanismo melhor ou não precisarem disto,
- efeitos de animação, já que tem maneiras melhores de obter o mesmo resultado,
- o que é considerado *deprecated*, mas que é mantido na versão completa porque muita gente ainda usa.

Assim fica menor. Se não precisa dessas coisas, é melhor usá-la.

[Anúncio que fala sobre isso](https://blog.jquery.com/2016/06/09/jquery-3-0-final-released/).

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/JavaScript/Conceptual.md).

Comment: Obrigado bigown

Answer (score 4):

Na [versão de lançamento do jQuery 3.0](https://blog.jquery.com/2016/06/09/jquery-3-0-final-released/), foi anunciado também a versão *slim* (esbelto, fino, leve) a qual [retirava algumas funções](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35424053/what-are-the-differences-between-normal-and-slim-package-of-jquery), que talvez você não quisesse utilizar, ou que você já utilizava/preferia utilizar em outra biblioteca *standalone*, e até mesmo funções que estavam obsoletas.

Algumas dessas funções foram:

- `jQuery.fn.extend`;
- `jQuery.fn.load`;
- `jQuery.each`;
- `jQuery.expr.filters.animated`;
- Configurações AJAX como `jQuery.ajaxSettings.xhr`, `jQuery.ajaxPrefilter`, `jQuery.ajaxSetup`, `jQuery.ajaxPrefilter`, `jQuery.ajaxTransport`, `jQuery.ajaxSetup`;
- *Parse* de XML como `jQuery.parseXML`;
- Efeitos de Animação como `jQuery.easing`, `jQuery.Animation`, `jQuery.speed`, já que existem outras maneiras de obter o desejado.

#### Adendo

- Relacionado ao último tópico, muitas vezes é mais simples usar uma combinação de CSS e manipulação de classe para fazer as suas animações web.
- E o tamanho do arquivo *slim* (gzip) é aproximadamente 6k menor que a versão padrão, 23.6k vs 30k.

---

Se você não precisa do que foi citado, ou já usa de maneira *standalone*, é recomendado que você utilize a versão *slim* do jQuery, já que não tem motivos em você ficar carregando aquilo que não vai usar, não é?