# Jquery para subir pagina após clique em botão

Tags: html, jquery

Bom dia amigos,

Estou procurando a dias por uma função de "subir a pagina", quando o usuario clicar em um botão.

Só encontro opções de "adicionar botão Voltar para o Topo", mas eu não quero adicionar um botão, quero que o botão faça a pagina subir. Tipo "selecionar", e quando o usuário seleciona a pagina sobe.

Alguém conhece esse tipo de função e pode me indicar algum material?

Estava tentando fazer desse jeito.. haha

```
$document(onclick)function(){   
    $("[name='Selecionar']");
    window.scrollTo({
    top: 1000,
    behavior: "smooth"
});
```

Agora:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
   $('.list_options.hotels .hotel_block .rooms_options > .price').click(function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        $('html, body').animate({scrollTop: 0}, 1000);
        event.stopPropagation();
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: Não entendi o teu problema. O que diferencia *"subir página"* de *"voltar ao topo"*? Tem algum exemplo ou site que faça isso pra nos mostrar?

Comment: Na verdade eu não quero adicionar um botão "voltar ao topo". Tenho varios botões "selecionar" e preciso que a pagina suba quando ele clicar em um desses.

Comment: Então seria como *"voltar ao topo"*, só que ao invés da página subir até o topo ela sobe até um elemento específico?

Comment: não, não.. desculpe... Vou te mandar o link do site e você verá os botões selecionar. Hoje eles ficam verdes ao serem clicados, mas eu gostaria que a pagina subisse quando o cliente clicasse neles.   https://bit.ly/2okGReI   Subir até o topo no caso.

Comment: Você quer que, ao clicar em "selecionar", página suba até o topo. Mas isso é exatamente um botão de voltar até o topo.
Ainda está confuso isso. Me parece que adicionar um `href="#algum-elemento"` resolveria teu problema

Comment: Então... o grande problema é que não tenho acesso ao HTML.

Comment: Já tentou [`window.scrollTo(0, 0)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/scrollTo) ?

Comment: Se vc não tem acesso ao HTML vc pelo menos tem acesso aos arquivos JS, ou tem como vc incluir algum JS no sei site? Pelo que reparei todos os btns Sleciona tem  class="purchase", então bast vc incluir na sua página um Script que pegue quando algum elemento com a class="purchase" for clicado a página rola pro topo. Mas para isso vc vai ter que ter no mínimo como incluir um script na página. Já reparei que a sua página tem jQuery, isso facilita ainda mais a coisa...

Comment: Isso! Eu tenho sim como adicionar JS no WP. Seria essa função que o brother acima citou?  window.scrollTo(0, 0) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gabriel pelo que conversamos no campo de comentário acho que pe isso que vc precisa.

Se vc já tem acesso ao JS do site, e seu projeto já tem jQuery basta vc criar um evento para a classe do btn para quando clicado voltar para o top da página.

Segue o exemplo, deixei dois btns, uma mais encima e outro lá embaixo, basta clicar neles que vc vai para o topo da página:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.price').click(function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        $('html, body').animate({scrollTop: 0}, 1200);
        event.stopPropagation();
    });
});
```

```css
.price .purchase {
    background: #00b0cd;
    background-size: 15px;
    color: #fff;
    font-family: Roboto;
    font-weight: 600;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    padding: '';
    margin: '';
}
p {
    margin: 1000px auto;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
     
<p class="price"><a href="#" class="purchase" title="Selecionar">Selecionar</a></p>
<p class="price"><a href="#" class="purchase" title="Selecionar">Selecionar</a></p>
```

Comment: Fantastico Hugo! Só uma ultima pergunta... no js consigo selecionar pelo "title"? pq meu medo é o seguinte... posso ter outros a.purchase no site que não são pra subir... Mas, só tenho "selecionar" nesta pagina msm.

Comment: @GabrielSalomão sim vc pode pegar assim `$('a[title="Selecionar"]')` no lugar onde está `$('.go-top')`

Comment: Brother, não funcionou ainda, acredita? haha... Essa parte do site, ela é bem complicada, pq não tenho acesso a nada... Semana passada fiz uma alteração de titulo de label e funcionou com Jquery, agr esse caso não tá rolando... Já tentei trocar pra window e load em vez de ready... testei todos os possiveis seletores pra fazer dar certo e não rolou.

Comment: @GabrielSalomão da forma mais simples como o seletor `.price` olha se funciona. Edite a resposta com o script já. Vc pode colocar o caminho inteiro do estilo do btn, no link que vc falou ficaria algo assim `$(' .list_options.hotels .hotel_block .rooms_options > .price ')` para testar tb

Comment: Reparei que a versão do seu jQuery aparentemente é bem antiga `jquery.js?ver=1.12.4` já está na 3.3.1! As vezes isso tb pode estar influenciando

Comment: Pois então brother... Colei lá em cima como está o codigo agr e continua sem funcionar... Sei que o seletor está correto, pq fiz uma alteração de "focus" com CSS nele e tá funcionando, provavel que seja por conta da versão msm do JQuery...

Comment: @GabrielSalomão se aqui funciona lá era para funcionar tb, testei tb com vários seletores e funcionou com todos... acho que a versão pode ser o problema, mas não tenho conhecimento para afirmar. Eu sei por exemplo que o jquery.slim.js por exemplo tem algumas limitações de animação, mas não acredito que esse é o seu problema... https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/171822/quais-as-diferen%C3%A7as-entre-as-vers%C3%B5es-do-jquery-normal-e-o-slim

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/83279/discussion-between-gabriel-salomao-and-hugocsl).