# O que acontece se eu não usar a versão Slim do jQuery com o Bootstrap?

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

Na [documentação do Bootstrap 4](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/getting-started/download/#bootstrapcdn), ele orienta a usar a build Slim do jQuery. Existe algum problema em usar a versão normal e completa do jQuery no meu projeto? Há alguma incompatibilidade?

Answer (score 3):

Tiago a questão é que o jQuery padrão tem uma série de coisas que não são usadas no Bootstrap como Animações por JS, `AJAX` e outros métodos deprecados e antigos. Por isso eles indicam a versão `Slim`, que além de ser menor em `kbs` é uma versão mais enxuta das funcionalidades. ***Mas se vc vai usar `AJAX` ou o método `.animate()` ai vc pode importar a versão completa do jQuery que não tem problema!***

Agora como vc pode ver na documentação do jQuery tanto a versão completa quando a Slim tem sua versão minificada, no casso `compressed` e `uncompressed` https://jquery.com/download/

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Diferença em `kb`

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Recomendo que leia essa resposta para ter mais detalhes entre a versão completa e a `Slim` [Quais as diferenças entre as versões do jQuery normal e o slim?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/171822/quais-as-diferen%C3%A7as-entre-as-vers%C3%B5es-do-jquery-normal-e-o-slim)

Comment: Isso quer dizer q, caso use essas funcionalidades, não tem problema usar SÓ a release completa?

Comment: @LipESprY na verdade na documentação do BS não da muitos detalhes pq eles usam a Slim, mas o fato é que o BS não usa por padrão AJAX em nada, assim como não usa o método .animate() http://api.jquery.com/animate/, então não tem porque importa-los, isso te economiza alguns KBs. **Mas se quiser usar a versão completa não tem problema**